# Math to find edge between two boxes

Tags: javascript, math, canvas

I am building prototype tool to draw simple diagrams.

I need to draw an arrow between two boxes, the problem is i have to find edges of two boxes so that the arrow line does not intersect with the box.

This is the drawing that visualize my problem:
[image: Algorithm]

How to find x1,y1 and x2,y2 ?

-- UPDATE --

After 2 days finding solution, this is example & function that i use:

```
var box1 = { x:1,y:10,w:30,h:30 };
var box2 = { x:100,y:110,w:30,h:30 };

var edge1 = findBoxEdge(box1,box2,1,0);
var edge2 = findBoxEdge(box1,box2,2,0);

function findBoxEdge(box1,box2,box,distant) {
    var c1 = box1.x + box1.w/2;
    var d1 = box1.y + box1.h/2;
    var c2 = box2.x + box2.w/2;
    var d2 = box2.y + box2.h/2;
    var w,h,delta_x,delta_y,s,c,e,ox,oy,d;

    if (box == 1) {
        w = box1.w/2;
        h = box1.h/2;
    } else {
        w = box2.w/2;
        h = box2.h/2;
    }

    if (box == 1) {
        delta_x = c2-c1;
        delta_y = d2-d1;
    } else {
        delta_x = c1-c2;
        delta_y = d1-d2;
    }
    w+=5;
    h+=5;

    //intersection is on the top or bottom
    if (w*Math.abs(delta_y) > h * Math.abs(delta_x)) {
        if (delta_y > 0) {
            s = [h*delta_x/delta_y,h];
            c = "top";
        }
        else {
            s = [-1*h*delta_x/delta_y,-1*h];
            c = "bottom";
        }
    } 
    else {
    //intersection is on the left or right
        if (delta_x > 0) {
            s = [w,w*delta_y/delta_x];
            c = "right";
        }
        else {
            s = [-1*w,-1*delta_y/delta_x];
            c = "left";
        }
    }

    if (typeof(distant) != "undefined") {
        //for 2 paralel distant of 2e
        e = distant;

        if (delta_y == 0) ox = 0;
        else ox = e*Math.sqrt(1+Math.pow(delta_x/delta_y,2))

        if (delta_x == 0) oy = 0;
        else oy = e*Math.sqrt(1+Math.pow(delta_y/delta_x,2))

        if (delta_y != 0 && Math.abs(ox + h * (delta_x/delta_y)) <= w) {
            d = [sgn(delta_y)*(ox + h * (delta_x/delta_y)),sgn(delta_y)*h];
        } 
        else if (Math.abs(-1*oy + (w * delta_y/delta_x)) <= h) {
            d = [sgn(delta_x)*w,sgn(delta_x)*(-1*oy + w * (delta_y/delta_x))];
        }
        if (delta_y != 0 && Math.abs(-1*ox+(h * (delta_x/delta_y))) <= w) {
            d = [sgn(delta_y)*(-1*ox + h * (delta_x/delta_y)),sgn(delta_y)*h];
        }
        else if (Math.abs(oy + (w * delta_y/delta_x)) <= h) {
            d = [sgn(delta_x)*w,sgn(delta_x)*(oy + w * (delta_y/delta_x))];
        }

        if (box == 1) {
            return [Math.round(c1 +d[0]),Math.round(d1 +d[1]),c];
        } else {
            return [Math.round(c2 +d[0]),Math.round(d2 +d[1]),c];       
        }
    } else {
        if (box == 1) {
            return [Math.round(c1 +s[0]),Math.round(d1 +s[1]),c];
        } else {
            return [Math.round(c2 +s[0]),Math.round(d2 +s[1]),c];       
        }

    }
```

Comment: the problem is i need to draw an *arrow*. So if the center point still in the box, it will look weird.

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem? You could simply draw a filled box right on top of the line from center to center.

Comment: yes bebraw, this is a problem. Because if i cover line with box, the arrow tip will be hidden.

Comment: Here's one idea. Treat the line from center to center (CtC) as a vector and the scale and offset to fit between. You'll need some basic trig to figure out the factors. There's a triangle (CtC, xOffset, yOffset) that you can use for this.

Comment: It might be even easier to do this with two vectors. Calculate the center of CtC and make the other vector point at one rect and the other to the remaining one. Figure out needed scaling factors individually. Once you are done, combine the results and draw your line.

Comment: yes bebraw. The problem is how to determine offset from the line to the center of the box, so the arrow tip will not be covered with box.

Comment: Just came by this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476020/code-golf-calculating-the-intersection-between-box-and-line . Line-line intersection per each edge seems like the ticket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[tl;dr -> Look at the jsbin code-example](http://jsbin.com/ipifat/7/edit#javascript,live)

It is our goal to draw a line from the edges of two Rectangles A & B that would be drawn through their centers.
Therefore we'll have to determine where the line *pierces* through the edge of a Rect.
We can assume that our `Rect` is an object containing `x` and `y` as offset from the upper left edge and `width` and `height` as dimension offset.

[image: different rectangles]

This can be done by the following code. The Method you should look at closely is `pointOnEdge`.

```
// starting with Point and Rectangle Types, as they ease calculation
var Point = function(x, y) { 
  return { x: x, y: y }; 
};
var Rect  = function(x, y, w, h) {
  return { x: x, y: y, width: w, height: h };
};
var isLeftOf = function(pt1, pt2) { return pt1.x < pt2.x; };
var isAbove  = function(pt1, pt2) { return pt1.y < pt2.y; };
var centerOf = function(rect) {
  return Point(
    rect.x + rect.width / 2,
    rect.y + rect.height / 2
  );
};
var gradient = function(pt1, pt2) {
  return (pt2.y - pt1.y) / (pt2.x - pt1.x);
};    
var aspectRatio = function(rect) { return rect.height / rect.width; };

// now, this is where the fun takes place
var pointOnEdge = function(fromRect, toRect) {
  var centerA = centerOf(fromRect),
      centerB = centerOf(toRect),
      // calculate the gradient from rectA to rectB
      gradA2B = gradient(centerA, centerB),
      // grab the aspectRatio of rectA
      // as we want any dimensions to work with the script
      aspectA = aspectRatio(fromRect),

      // grab the half values, as they are used for the additional point
      h05 = fromRect.width / 2,
      w05 = fromRect.height / 2,

      // the norm is the normalized gradient honoring the aspect Ratio of rectA
      normA2B = Math.abs(gradA2B / aspectA),

      // the additional point
      add = Point(
        // when the rectA is left of rectB we move right, else left
        (isLeftOf(centerA, centerB) ? 1 : -1) * h05,
        // when the rectA is below
        (isAbove(centerA, centerB)  ? 1 : -1) * w05
      );

  // norm values are absolute, thus we can compare whether they are
  // greater or less than 1
  if (normA2B < 1) {
    // when they are less then 1 multiply the y component with the norm
    add.y *= normA2B;
  } else {
    // otherwise divide the x component by the norm
    add.x /= normA2B;
  }
  // this way we will stay on the edge with at least one component of the result
  // while the other component is shifted towards the center

  return Point(centerA.x + add.x, centerA.y + add.y);
};
```

I wrote a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ipifat/7/edit#javascript,live), you can use to test with some boxes (lower part, in the ready method):

You might want to take a look at [a little Geometry helper](https://github.com/Tharabas/NativeJS/blob/master/src/Geometry.js) I wrote some time ago on top of  [prototype.js](http://www.prototypejs.org/)

I really hope, that this helps you with your problem ;)

Comment: WOW Great, I really appreaciate the answer! i'm asking same question at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108113/find-edge-between-two-boxes, I don't know if this is allowed. But a guy there solved my problem too. Now i run to another problem, how to add double line between the boxes?

Answer (score 1):

To draw a line between those boxes, you'd first have to define where you want the line to be.

[image: two boxes]

Apparently you want to draw the lines/arrows from the right edge of Rect A to the left edge of 
 Rect B, somewhat like this:

[image: two boxes with a link]

Assuming your know the origin (upper left `Point` as { x, y } of a `Rect`) and its `Size` (width and height), you first want to determine the position of the center of the edges:

[image: center of edges highlighted]

```
var rectA, rectB; // I assume you have those data
var rectARightEdgeCenter = {
  // x is simply the origin's x plus the width
  x: rectA.origin.x + rectA.size.width,
  // for y you need to add only half the height to origin.y
  y: rectA.origin.y + rectA.size.height / 2.0
}
var rectBLeftEdgeCenter = {
  // x will be simply the origin's x
  x: rectB.origin.x,
  // y is half the height added to the origin's y, just as before
  y: rectB.origin.y + rectB.size.height / 2.0
}
```

The more interesting question would be how to determine, from which edge to which other edge you might want to draw the lines in a more dynamic scenario.

If your boxes just pile up from left to right the given solution will fit, 
but you might want to check for minimum distances of the edges, to determine a possible *best* arrow.

Comment: Do'h I didn't read your comment ... so my solution does not fit your problem, sry :/

Comment: Thanks for your effort for this answer. Yes, that is what i'm looking for, find the edge coordinate. Your answer is correct only for that case (A is on the left of B). What if Box A is on top Box B? What if Box A is slightly right but still on top of Box B? and so on...